# switching images in application

Tags: java, android

I have decided that i want to use images for the quesiton of my application, where as before i was using text.

The code below changes the questions, which are stored in a string array.

I now have an array of images also called questions

How would i change image for each question here?

instead of setText what would i use?

```
    ques.setText(questions[rnd2]);
if(questions[rnd2]=="x")
{
 change_question(rnd2);
}
}
questions[rnd2]="x";
```

Thank you in advanced.

KCCman

Comment: Don't use operator `==` to compare strings. Use `equals` `questions[rnd2]=="x"` -> `questions[rnd2].equals("x")`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[0] = "R.drawable.q1"; // your image ID
arr[1] = "R.drawable.q2";
arr[2] = "R.drawable.q2";

imageView.setImageBitmap(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to put the images in your resource folders and just change either the background drawable of a view or the source drawaable of an imageview based on that.

So just put the images you want in your resources folders, and for example:

```
if(question == 1)
{
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.question1);
}
```

So just store those resource Ids in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the images to ques (TextView) itself, then use this.

ques.setBackgroundResource(imageIds[rnd2]);

[sample imageIds

```
  imageIds = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2}
]
```